# Creating a table from an image in python

Tags: python, ocr

I've never used OCR before and I was wondering if anyone can recommend a decent OCR for python that would be able to convert the following image into a 2D array?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

OCR stands for Optical CHARACTER Recognition.  Any generic OCR, even paid high-quality commercial product, will be very unreliable on this image.  I tried one - it produces some dots, and keeps most other areas as pictures due to lack of characters.

To process this reliably, especially if the volume is high, I would write an image analysis routine (if images are consistent) or use some specialized customizable tool.  To be specific, I would use [ABBYY FlexiCapture](http://www.wisetrend.com/abbyy-flexicapture/) (because I have access to it) and create a quick template to detect a matrix of 'objects' (black blobs) in table-like pattern.  10 minutes of work at most.